# Taking two sql query into one query working too slow

Tags: php, mysql, sql

What I am trying to do is to create 1 query
which will do the following check:

I've got 2 tables both in 'yesnotmp' database.
one is called `msg_t` which contains all the messages,It has a lot of columns.What I care about in this query is those two `send_time`,`status`,`phone`,`sushi_sub_id`.

Here I am getting all of the phone, sushi_sub_id records of yesterday. (And it works)

```
SELECT phone, sushi_sub_id FROM `yesnotmp`.`msg`
        LEFT JOIN `yesnotmp`.`msg_t` ON (`msg`.`id`=`msg_t`.`msg_id`)
        WHERE `msg_t`.`send_time` BETWEEN '2013-06-02' AND '2013-06-03' 
            AND `msg_t`.`status` = 'Failure.Provider.Connection'
```

What I am trying to do is to check on the `retry` table how many `phone` was inserted with the same `sushi_sub_id`and how many wasn't. (this query is taking really long time)

```
SELECT 
    Sum(CASE WHEN (SELECT Count(*) FROM `retry` AS `rty` WHERE `rty`.`phone` = `msgs`.`phone` AND `rty`.`sushi_subscription_id`=`msgs`.`sushi_sub_id`) > 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS `In_Retry`,
Sum(CASE WHEN (SELECT Count(*) FROM `retry` AS `rty` WHERE `rty`.`phone` = `msgs`.`phone` AND `rty`.`sushi_subscription_id`=`msgs`.`sushi_sub_id`) > 0 THEN 0 ELSE 1 END) AS `Not_In_Retry`
FROM 
    (SELECT phone, sushi_sub_id FROM `yesnotmp`.`msg`
        LEFT JOIN `yesnotmp`.`msg_t` ON (`msg`.`id`=`msg_t`.`msg_id`)
        WHERE `msg_t`.`send_time` BETWEEN '2013-06-02' AND '2013-06-03' 
            AND `msg_t`.`status` = 'Failure.Provider.Connection') AS `msgs`
```

Comment: You say 'it works', but the WHERE clause effectively renders your LEFT [outer] JOIN as an [inner] JOIN, so you might as well write it that way to begin with... SELECT m.phone
     , m.sushi_sub_id 
  FROM msg m 
  JOIN msg_t t
    ON t.msg_id = m.id 
 WHERE t.send_time BETWEEN '2013-06-02' AND '2013-06-03' 
   AND t.status = 'Failure.Provider.Connection';

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Slight alteration I would suggest... don't sum via selects for each column, but simple join and count them directly.  First, your LEFT-JOIN to Msg_T table but with a WHERE clause on the Msg_T table forces it into an INNER JOIN.

You are looking for message time activity between a given date and status.  To help optimize the query, I would have an index on MSG_T on (status, send_time) so it can jump directly to your "Failure.Provider.Connection", then directly to the date range in question.

Now, the retry table.  This can be a LEFT join as you may never HAVE a retry entry (correct me if I'm wrong on that).

```
SELECT 
      msg_t.phone, 
      msg_t.sushi_sub_id,
      max( case when rty.phone is not null then 1 else 0 end ) as In_Retry,
      max( case when rty.phone is  null then 1 else 0 end ) as Not_In_Retry
   FROM 
      yesnotmp.msg_t msg_t
         JOIN yesnotmp.msg msg
            ON msg_t.msg_id = msg.id
            LEFT JOIN `retry` rty
               ON  msg_t.phone = rty.phone
              AND msg_t.sushi_sub_id = rty.sushi_subscription_id
   WHERE 
          msg_t.status = 'Failure.Provider.Connection'
      AND msg_t.send_time BETWEEN '2013-06-02' AND '2013-06-03' 
   GROUP BY
      msg_t.phone, 
      msg_t.sushi_sub_id
```

EDIT --

Adjusted per edit attempts to clarify alias.field for phone, sushi_sub_id reference... Now, knowing proper table for fields, I would ensure msg_t table has index on all 4 parts for the query.

( status, send_time, phone, sushi_sub_id )

As for the "MAX( CASE...)".  Since this is done with a left-join to the retry table on the respective columns, if it has any record (1 or more), the "phone" will have a valid value.  If NO such record exists, it will be NULL.

Answer (score 2):

You are missing the group by clause. I would try to replace the count(*) with exists:

```
SELECT 
    Sum(CASE WHEN exists(SELECT 1 FROM `retry` AS `rty` 
    WHERE `rty`.`phone` = `msgs`.`phone` 
    AND `rty`.`sushi_subscription_id`=`msgs`.`sushi_sub_id`) 
    THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS `In_Retry`,
    Sum(CASE WHEN exists(SELECT 1 FROM `retry` AS `rty` 
    WHERE `rty`.`phone` = `msgs`.`phone` 
    AND `rty`.`sushi_subscription_id`=`msgs`.`sushi_sub_id`) 
    THEN 0 ELSE 1 END) AS `Not_In_Retry`,
    phone, sushi_sub_id
FROM 
    (SELECT phone, sushi_sub_id FROM `yesnotmp`.`msg`
        LEFT JOIN `yesnotmp`.`msg_t` ON (`msg`.`id`=`msg_t`.`msg_id`)
        WHERE `msg_t`.`send_time` BETWEEN '2013-06-02' AND '2013-06-03' 
            AND `msg_t`.`status` = 'Failure.Provider.Connection') AS `msgs`
GROUP BY phone, sushi_sub_id
```